# RoomDB SQL Query / data modelling problem

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I'm using RoomDB to store entities in my app, so far I've only needed relatively trivial queries such as `SELECT * FROM table` and `DELETE * FROM table` as well as slightly more complex things such as a join of 2 tables to return composite models, like `SELECT * from tableA INNER JOIN ON tableB tableA.tableBId = tableB.tableBId`.

So far, so good. Now, I have something I've not dealt with before, and I'm not sure whether I'm A) modelling my data wrong (so no query will be possible to create these models) or B) I don't know parts of SQL that are required to make this work.

I'm far from a SQL expert, but have used it on and off for a few years.

Below are the simplest example of the models (marked with @Entity such that RoomDB tables are generated) of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
data class FooPopulated(
    val fooId: Long,
    @Embedded
    val barOne: Bar,
    @Embedded
    val barTwo: Bar,
    @Embedded
    val barThree: Bar
)

@Entity(primaryKeys = ["fooId"])
data class FooUnpopulated(
    val fooId: Long,
    val barOneId: Long,
    val barTwoId: Long,
    val barThreeId: Long
)

@Entity(primaryKeys = ["barId"])
data class Bar(
    val barId: Long,
    val name: String
)
```

So there will be 2 tables; `Bar` and `FooUnpopulated` and I want to run a query that will "join" the `FooUnpopulated` table entries with the `Bar` table entries, in such a way that I get back a collection of `FooPopulated`.

I am stumped, can anyone advise? Is my `FooPopulated` model just "wrong" in that it doesn't define a valid relationship which can be satisfied by a SQL query, or, am I missing that magic SQL keywords/understanding to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one to one relation and can define FooPopulated like:

```
data class FooPopulated{
 @Embeded
 val fooUnpopulated: FooUnpopulated,
 @Relation(parentColumn = "barOneId", childColumn = "barId")
 val barOne: Bar,
 @Relation( parentColumn = "barTwoId", childColumn = "barId")
 val barTwo: Bar,
 @Relation( parentColumn = "barThreeId", childColumn = "barId")
 val barThree: Bar
}
```

Now you can define a function in your DAO to get this object:

```
@Transaction
@Query("YOUR QUERY HERE")
fun getFooPopulated(): List<FooPopulated>
```

More details here:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-one

Comment: Nice, makes sense (I think :D) - I suppose I can quickly test that this works, then decide if this is actually how I want to model my data, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks. I have forgotten commas between the fields and forgot to update the variable names. So updated the answer.

Comment: Also, I think you changed my `FooPopulated` model in your answer to have `fooUnpopulated` field, instead of just `fooId`

Comment: yes, I have embedded the whole FooUnpopulated object. To get the fooId from the result,  you have to call objectName.fooUnpopulated.fooId in your code.